# how to echo the image and not the url using php

Tags: php, image, url, curl, echo

I want to echo the image from this link using php curl:

```
$url = "https://instagram.flwo4-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-19/s320x320/41447767_1505663449534377_4011087695949332480_n.jpg?tp=1&_nc_ht=instagram.flwo4-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_ohc=Jx7DbSAB_G4AX_Rg_er&edm=ABfd0MgBAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=43e068e4a4b667b4570d3611f90e4788&oe=60B7B609&_nc_sid=7bff83"
```

when I do it, the browser display the url of the image as result and not the image as it's displayed when we access the link directly.
If I use filegetcontent() the image is not displayed but a lot of symbols in the screen.
I want to display the image when I echo it and not the url text, as it is displayed when we access the link.

Answer (score 0):

Simply :

```
echo "<img src='$url'>";
```

Nice image btw, you shoulden't post your links here if it's private :P

[image]

Comment: Well, first, thanks for answering, it's not a private image it's an image of a celebrety bigdwastv from yt, well the image displayed in my website is broken, it's not like here in stackoverflow, but it's like corrupted when I do it.

Comment: This icon shows that the image could not be found, can you show us more of your code ?

Comment: simple code brother:
<?php
$link = "https://instagram.flwo4-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-19/s320x320/41447767_1505663449534377_4011087695949332480_n.jpg?tp=1&_nc_ht=instagram.flwo4-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_ohc=Jx7DbSAB_G4AX_Rg_er&edm=ABfd0MgBAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=43e068e4a4b667b4570d3611f90e4788&oe=60B7B609&_nc_sid=7bff83";
echo "<img src='$link'>";
?>

Comment: Sorry for the late answer.
And it gives like https://i.imgur.com/ufJHy1n.png on your html page ?
(I tought the varialbe was useful for something but here it's not, you can put the link between the ' ' directly)

Comment: Hi, sorry am late too, I still have that problem, when I try with this url: "https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvrg5.jpg" it shows the image, but me I have to use instagram link for the image.

Answer (score 0):

The picture is displayed in my website only when I use this code ...

```
<?php

$remoteImage = "https://instagram.flwo4-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.288519/s320x320/41447767_1505663449534377_4011087695949332480_n.jpg? tp=1&_nc_ht=instagram.flwo41.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_ohc=Jx7DbSAB_G4AX_Rg_er&edm=ABfd0MgBAAAA&ccb=7- 4&oh=43e068e4a4b667b4570d3611f90e4788&oe=60B7B609&_nc_sid=7bff83";
$imginfo = getimagesize($remoteImage);
header("Content-type: {$imginfo['mime']}");
readfile($remoteImage);
?>
```

Any other solution?